# How to identify one out of multiple html input type="submit"

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I need to call the show button via code but in page we have multiple show buttons without id. How to hit a particular "show" button suppose 3rd show?

[image]

Comment: Give them different IDs.

Comment: I can't edit the Html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no way of uniquely identifying each submit (far, far from ideal) - you can simply reference the index:

`document.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]')[2]`

If you have jQuery on the page you may also write:

`$('[type="submit"]')[2]`

Again, to reiterate, this is not a great way of achieving this at all - but given restrictions you have over the mark-up, it answers the question you're asking.

As an aside, the documents themselves may not have `id` attributes, but try and see if there is something uniquely identifiable about one of the parent elements perhaps, and traverse from there.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll implement the same and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `selector` `$('input[type=submit]')` to get all `input` which has `type=submit`. More over you need to get 3rd submit button then use `:nth(2)` like `$('input[type=submit]:nth(2)')`. `:nth` will return element based on starting index with 0.

[Learn more about jquery selector here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

You can check it below. You should be using `submitButton.click()` instead of `submitButton.val()`. I have used `submitButton.val()` for just display purpose.

```js
function getThirdSubmitButton() {
  var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]:nth(2)');
  alert(submitButton.val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Show 1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Show 2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Show 3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Show 4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Get 3rd submit button" onclick="getThirdSubmitButton()" />
```

Comment: @JAYMEE you’re right. I assume that OP is using jquery. And regarding to query returning jQuery element, OP wants to perform click event. And jQuery element can also perform click. So it can fulfil OP’s requirement. I saw your answer and it is absolutely correct. I just tend to share one more way to achieve the same.